# How to read videos in openCV on a linux machine?

Tags: files, software-installation, video, opencv

I am trying to run [some code](http://pastebin.com/ym5Yi6cH) from the internet (which works perfectly fine on another computer). But the software doesn't work because it can't open video files in openCV.
According to a person I had the chance to meet, it is because I didn't install a specific thing when installing openCV or codeblocks.

I would like to know how I can figure out what I need to install to get the code to work and how I can afterwards install it.

```
  - I am using linux mint 
  - openCV 3.x in Code::Blocks IDE
```

**EDIT**:

The code compiles and runs perfectly fine, but what I get is the message on line 54 of my software. Yes the path to the video is correct and doesn't contain spaces! Yes I am talking about the openCV library.

This is the relevant code:

```
// Camera Capture
VideoCapture test("/home/john/car.mpeg");

if (!test.isOpened())
{
    cout << "file not opened"<<endl; // <- this is line 54
}
```

The output is `file not opened`.

The code I am trying to run is from [this tutorial](http://www.robot-home.it/blog/en/software/ball-tracker-con-filtro-di-kalman/).

Comment: What error message are you getting? Does the code compile? What do you mean by "can't open video files in openCV"? Are you talking about the [openCV library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)? Why would it be able to open video files? It's a library, not a video player!

Comment: @terdon the code compiles  and runs perfectly fine, but what I get is the message on line 54 of my software. Yes the path to the video is correct and doesn't contain spaces! Yes I am talking about the openCV library. It should be able to work with video files to do image processing.

Comment: then please edit your question and add this information. What error? What line? All of that should be in your question as well. We can't help unless you explain what you are doing.

Comment: @terdon updated my post :) , any suggestions?

Comment: @trilolil you still haven't told us what "the message on line 54 of my software" **is**. If the file you are trying to open readable? does it contain a valid video file or image sequence?

Comment: "what I get is the message on line 54 of my software": what message? What software? What is on line 54 of this software? What is this code supposed to do? How are you testing it? On what input? You need to ask your question in such a way that someone can replicate what you are trying to do on their machine and try to debug it.

Comment: @terdon the post has been updated. I think it now does comply with the requirements. Any suggestions about my problem?

Comment: @steeldriver yes it does contain a perfectly valid video. The code works perfectly fine on another machine.

Comment: What exact version of OpenCV are you using? what is the output of `file /home/john/car.mpeg`

Comment: What is the exact codec of the video?

Comment: @steeldriver openCV-3.1.0 , inputting "file /home/john/car.mpeg" in my terminal outputs "/home/john/car.mpeg: MPEG sequence, v1, system multiplex"

Comment: @ctx 

codec_name=mpeg1video;
codec_long_name=MPEG-1 video;
profile=unknown;
codec_type=video;
codec_time_base=1/25;
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0];
codec_tag=0x0000;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the codec to open MPEG-1 videos:

You need libavcodec-dev to be able to decode and encode videos:
https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libavcodec-dev

You need libmpeg2-4-dev to support MPEG-1:
https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libmpeg2-4-dev

Comment: Thx for your answer, it is based on this tutorial: http://www.robot-home.it/blog/en/software/ball-tracker-con-filtro-di-kalman/ , whose code works perfectly fine on other machines. I just need to install something additional apparently...

Comment: As said this code should work as is, here (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) you can see that they don't use the open function neither.

Comment: Is it this package: https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libavcodec-dev

Comment: I think so, but am not sure though. I installed it quite some time ago. Any way to check?

Comment: I added another package which is needed to decode MPEG-1 videos.